# Applying re function to a mixed pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

Have the following dataframe *df*:

```
   RID                  Other_aided Ultibro Relvar
0  701              {_12,_101,_102}    {_9}    NaN
1  702                 {_7,_11,_16}    {_7}    NaN
2  703  {_12,_101,_102,_10,_11,_16}    {_7}    NaN
3  704                  {_5,_3,_16}     NaN    NaN
4  705       {_101,_102,_10,_3,_16}    {_6}    NaN
```

Would like to clean *df* by:

- removing `{}_` from the *data* columns, where it is there.
- *NaN*s need to replaced by NULL strings `''`.
- First ID column of ints (`RID`) needs to be protected.

Made the following function *f*:

```
import re
f = lambda x: re.sub(r'[^0-9,]','', x)
```

Running:

1. `df.Other_aided.apply(f)` works fine for a single column with proper data.
2. `df.Ultibro.apply(f)`, and `df.Relvar.apply(f)` fail with `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`, thanks to the *NaN*s.
3. So... thought of converting the *data* columns to strings would help with the code `df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda y: f(str(y)), axis=1)`. But this fails miserably, giving an inaccurate output ... like:

```
0         175,9,10,3,11,1612,101,102810109918280,
1                    159,10,37,11,16710710717281,
...
```

How can *df* be cleaned-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want use your function first replace `NaN`s to empty strings and then pass it to [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for element wise processing:

```
f = lambda x: re.sub(r'[^0-9,]','', x)
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].fillna('').applymap(f)
print (df)
   RID          Other_aided Ultibro Relvar
0  701           12,101,102       9       
1  702              7,11,16       7       
2  703  12,101,102,10,11,16       7       
3  704               5,3,16               
4  705      101,102,10,3,16       6
```

Or use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].fillna('').replace(r'[^0-9,]','', regex=True)
print (df)
   RID          Other_aided Ultibro Relvar
0  701           12,101,102       9       
1  702              7,11,16       7       
2  703  12,101,102,10,11,16       7       
3  704               5,3,16               
4  705      101,102,10,3,16       6
```

---

```
#if never missing values in first column, so no repacing it to empty strings
df = df.fillna('').replace(r'[^0-9,]','', regex=True)
print (df)
   RID          Other_aided Ultibro Relvar
0  701           12,101,102       9       
1  702              7,11,16       7       
2  703  12,101,102,10,11,16       7       
3  704               5,3,16               
4  705      101,102,10,3,16       6
```